# How can I change button value with stylish?

Tags: css, button, stylish

This is the button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value=" black "><input>
```

I want to change value "black" to "white" but I can't. How can I change the value with stylish?

Comment: the value of input can't be changed with css i think

Comment: you can simply write `button {color: #fff ;}` 
What exactly you mean by stylish.. ?

Comment: What is stylish ?
What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: this Question isn Not clear, can you please make your Question very Clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Stylish* is an add-on/extension that just allows you to inject CSS.  The `value` of that button is a JavaScript / DOM property; Stylish cannot change those.

You need to **install *Greasemonkey*** (Firefox) or *Tampermonkey* (Chrome).

Then you can run this userscript to change that value:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var btn = document.querySelector ("input[name='submitbutton']");
if (btn) {
    btn.value = "White";
}
else {
    alert ("From GM script: Button not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of a button using CSS.
Though it can be done using JavaScript.
This link might help you-

[javascript change value of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215792/javascript-change-value-of-button)