# Remove certain text value from list of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have a list of buttons. When one is clicked it appends the text "selected'" to the existing value of the button.

When one button is clicked I want to removed the text "selected" from the other buttons if the text is there.

Basically it should be like - Loop through all the buttons in the area (they all have a class of searchResult) and remove the value "selected" from each button if it is there.

Here is the code for each button:

```
<input type="button" class="searchResult" onclick="$(\'#usersToSend > *\').css(\'background-color\', \'#fff\');
var oldValue = this.value;
this.value=\'(selected) \' + oldValue; this.style.backgroundColor = \'#51CA3E\';
document.getElementById(\'hiddenUserFlag\').value = \''.$row['id'].'\';"
value="'.$row['username'].'">
```

Here is the code bit to pay attention to:

```
$(\'#usersToSend > *\').css(\'background-color\', \'#fff\');
var oldValue = this.value;
this.value=\'(selected) \' + oldValue;
this.style.backgroundColor = \'#51CA3E\';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215792/javascript-change-value-of-button

Comment: Add some of your code or create fiddle, that reproduces behavior of your situation. -1 for creating video, that is totally not required. Explain your problem in writing. Good question is part of answer.

Comment: I could see how you might think that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215792/javascript-change-value-of-button might be a duplicate answer, but for my question the button value is assigned from a database and I don't want to reload anything. Also as I said the best way of doing this would be to loop through each button inside the 'usersToSend' div and then remove the value '(selected)' if '(selected)' is there.

Comment: @user3011082 BTW, why are you using all those `\\` ?!

Comment: To escape (') because it's inside a php script sent in via ajax.

Comment: Well, as i wrote that your question had three lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method as shown below:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("button:contains('selected')").text(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.replace("selected","");
  })
  this.innerHTML+= "selected";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button-</button>
<button>button-</button>
<button>button-</button>
```

**Update:** The above will not work with `<input>` buttons. for those, use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) methods asfollows:

```js
$(":input").click(function(){
  $(":input").filter(function(){
    return this.value.indexOf("selected") > 0
  }).val(function(){
    return this.value.replace("selected","");
  })
  this.value+= "selected";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="button-" />
<input type="button" value="button-" />
<input type="button" value="button-" />
```

Comment: Thank you looks promising. I'll try it! :D

Comment: In the end I ended up just doing changing of background color instead of changing text value because of other issues as well. Thank you all so much for your helpful answers and comments!

Comment: The code snippet would work well for the situation you proposed. However, for me the buttons are created with a php script and sent in by ajax. All the script which I posted was inline script. That's also why I had to do \' to escape (')

Comment: @user3011082 i just asked out of curiosity... While replying to a comment, Please reply back below the respective comment otherwise it'll confuse somebody else.. :)